# Django: How to log out a user using Javascript's window.confirm()

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am making a web app using Django/Python. There is a navigation at the top of the web app, and if a user clicks on the 'logout' link a pop-up window using Javascript's window.confirm() asks them if they are sure that they want to log out.
I have the following in `logout.js`:

```
function logout() {
    if(window.confirm("Are you you sure that you want to log out?")) {
        window.open("index.html");
    }
    return;
}
```

If a user selects 'OK' in the pop-up that is displayed, I want the app to log the user out and display the home page of the app (represented by `index.html`). However, to log the user out I need to do this in views.py. I have the following code in views.py:

```
def logoutUser(request):
    if request.POST:
        if request.POST.get("confirm-btn"):
            logout(request)
            return render(request, 'index.html')
        if request.POST.get("cancel-btn"):
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
    return render(request, 'logout.html')
```

I have a page called logout.html which has two buttons, and if a user clicks the confirm button they are logged out and taken to the home page. However, I want a pop-up to be displayed instead.

My question is, how can I connect the Javascript code for the logout pop-up with the backend code in `views.py` that deals with the user logging out. If a user presses 'OK' in the `window.confirm()`, how can I actually log the user out using `logout(request)` and display `index.html` of the app? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try sending a POST request from JS to your view? Intuitively it seems the easiest route. If you need directions I can show a little example.

Comment: I've never done something like this before, so I would highly appreciate it if you could show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive if it took me a while.

I am not a great expert, but in Django 1.11 I use a strategy like this to send data and requests from JS / jQuery to the backend:

**JS**:

```
function logout(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/logout/',
    method: "GET",
    data : "logout",
    success: function () {
      console.log("logged out");
      return true
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("nope, it didn't work");
      return false
    }
  });
}
```

Which implies you need to set up an appropriate address in your **urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
...
]
```

and then in your **views.py**

```
def logout(request):
    if "logout" in request.GET:
        ....
```

If the request is simple and does not require special protection I tend to use a GET, otherwise a POST.

In case you wanted to use a POST (probably more compatible with your existing code) you would need to pass also the CSRF token, **modifying the initial JS** like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/logout/',
  method: "POST",
  data : "logout",
  headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
  ....
```

In that case your JS would need to get the token from the html. You can inject the token by setting the appropriate variable from inside your **html page**. The value would get populated by django when it renders the page, through injection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var csrftoken = '{{ csrf_token }}';
</script>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have been trying to use the solution. I have a query, though. Is there a way that, after the `ajax` function is called **successfully**, the page redirects to the `login` page? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, assuming you want the redirect to happen from Django, `redirect` is your function. Check this tutorial out, it should be straightforward: https://realpython.com/django-redirects/